# how does opencv work?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm if there are  component diagrams  or a documentation about the opencv library works with each others, how do they depend to one another ? for example the `highGUI.dll`  need `core.dll`  but doesn't `imagproc.dll` I looked in google, but didn't I get anything !

any idea ?

Comment: you can browse the source there : https://github.com/itseez/opencv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK the **core** module is the only dependency of other modules. And it seems intuitive and natural that the core functionality and the definitions of basic structures such as `Mat` are used by the other modules (which are independent on each other).

This concept is also described in the very first chapter of the [*official OpenCV's online documentation*](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html), which should be the first place where you should look for the answers in terms of OpenCV :)

And in case you just need to know the dependencies of the binaries of your application, what you actually need to do is to build your application and drag-n-drop the binaries into [the Dependency Walker (depends.exe)](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), which will show you what `.dll` files your app needs.

Comment: does that mean that the other component  are not depending on each others ?  I didn't found this on the page  ?

Comment: look at the source code and you will see, if they call each other

Comment: @jambono: I believe so, but I haven't seen that kind of statement in their documentation either. BTW is there any specific reason why you need the diagram of OpenCV's modules dependencies?

Comment: if you go in the module highgui there https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp so  you will see that there is an #include "opencv2/core.hpp" as expected

Comment: @Engine: My previous comment was supposed to be tagged with `@Engine` instead of `@jambono` -_-

Comment: I have a program, and I want to build it as dll, since it use opencv I want reduce that the number of use library and if I'm sure that'll be ok even delete some code from them

Comment: @Engine: So what you need to do is to build your application and drag-n-drop the binaries into [the Dependency Walker (depends.exe)](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). It will show you what `.dll` files your app needs.

Comment: @LihO thanks for your answers, it sound pretty interesting I'll try it

Comment: @Engine: To be 100% sure, you should then start your application from Dependency Walker. It will also check if additional DLLs are loaded at runtime.